# Массив со строковыми индексами (С++)

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

Как создать массив (или его альтернативу наподобие списка), чтобы в качестве индекса элемента использовалась строка, то есть примерно так:

```
Mass["Василий"] = 3
```

Вроде помню что что-то подобное было, но не помню что, буду благодарен за помощь)

Comment: Можно воспользоваться ассоциативным контейнером `std::map<std::string, int> Mass;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь стандартным отображением `map<string, ....>`, или напишите свой класс, в которой реализуйте оператор `operator[](const char*)`.